# Shell script to send a custom message to users listed in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to write a shell script, that opens **two text files** (e.g message.txt, users.txt) and **sends the message found** in the first file ($1) **to every single user found in the second file** ($2)?

If a user is currently **logged in**, the message should be sent with the **"write" command**, else (if they are **not currently logged in**), it will be sent as a **"mail"**.

I tried running this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

msg=`cat $1`
input=$2

while IFS= read -r usr
do
        `write $usr $msg`
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]
        #here I tried checking if the $usr found in the $2 file is not online
        `mail $usr $msg`
        #The Subject part could also be a problem here
        fi
done < "$input"
```

However, I am unsure how the mail part should be done, when running the code it even says that there is an **error** on **line 22 (where I tried mailing the user)**.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to send an email via bash:

```
mail -s 'message subject' username@gmail.com <<< 'testing message body'
```

So in your case, you should add the *-s* parameter before the **subject** and you should add the **body** to add to your email. (you can use '' for empty body)

Another syntax to perform that:

```
echo "text message body" | mail -s "message subject" username@gmail.com
```

PS: You should not use the *backticks* (*``*) for the mail command